# Avoid shocking with he help of isolation transformer

Tags: power, output

Is it possible to touch the output of islation tramsformer with out getting shocked ?

Comment: Depends on what the other end of the coil and the input is connected to, please be specific. "Is it possible" questions are generally closed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to touch one output.  I wouldn't advise it, just in case one output is accidentally grounded, or the insulation is faulty.  But it is intended to save you from shocks if you do touch one output.

Isolation does not save you if you touch both outputs simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse "ISOLATION" with safety. It simply means the circuit on one side is isolated from the circuit on the other. The output side could be at kilovolt levels...

Is it possible... of course... It's also possible to pull the trigger of a six-shot revolver against your head with only 5 bullets in it without blowing your brains out.

Do you want to take a chance... NO!